# How can you procedurally generate objects with physics in the same area?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I have a truck and thousands of coins to pile on top of the truck bed.  I basically have the coins stacked in rows and columns.  However, I noticed that the higher the coin drops, the harder the physics are applied and by the end of the simulation, most of the coins are on the floor.

If I drop the coin at a shorter distance, I believe I can make more coins stay on the truck's bed, but if I stack all the coins in one place they just explode out when I run the simulation.

Is it possible that I can generate a few coins at a time procedurally in the same place, so the distance from the coins and the truck's bed is smaller?  Or is there a better solution to what I'm trying to do?

The best analogy I can think to explain the behavior I want is water flowing from a faucet. The water is generated in one place that I can easily turn off and on.  Just need the same thing for coins. [image] [image]

Comment: Seems like it would be best to use particle system for dropping the coins from the same height in random directions.

Comment: Particles don't act as rigid bodies so they will not take the shape of the coins into account.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your Q is ...

### **Addon**

- for such thing I would use object generating particles and than use addon [**Copy Particles to Rigid Bodies**](https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-particles-to-rigid-bodies/563269) from Liero (even last version written for 2.8 works in 3.4)

---

---

**TIP for your current scene ...** to make speed of fall constant try to use ...

### **Force Field**

- you can add *Force Field* object > type **Drag** to slow down falling (like Air). Enable Fall-Off affect higher objects more than lower ones.

[image]

As an extension ... here is a comparison ...

[image]

[image]

Left - Keyframed motion - *Cube* with *Constant* speed based on lower *Cube* from middle RG sim. Speed of both red (30 m) and green cube (6 m) is the same.

[image]

Middle - regular Rigid Body

[image]

Right - Rigid Body affected by Force Field > Drag ... with Linear adjusted to match end frame with red cube.

[image]

From these baked F-curves you can see - Cube affected by Drag is speeding up at the first 6 frames, but than it falls at constant speed (even without Fall-Off).

Comment: Oh, that Addon works nicely, at least on my first little test. That's something I wish Blender had built in. But what about the _Drag_? That's in the _Particle Settings_, not _Rigid Bodies_.

Comment: Yep, _Drag_ force field is better for this... only problem is, the gravity works against the drag as well, so particles that are much higher will still accelerate more or you set the drag strength that the lower ones are much too slow. I think the addon you mention is the best to get some kind of particle solution. Or just all coins starting to fall from a lower height like Chris' solution. Still, the slide works like drag as well, slowing particles down but still not defying gravity ;)

Comment: Drag has Fall-off parametr so you can control what part of coins to affect more and less gradually ... ad the Addon yeah I was a big fan for years :)

Comment: Of course, _Falloff_... my bad. But you could also get away if you just fiddle around with the values as I just found out. I took two spheres, bounciness at 1 on both, and let them fall on a ground (bounciness also 1). One sphere starts falling from a height of 3 meters, the other 28 meters. If I set the drag strength to 0.15 for _Linear_ and 0 for _Quadratic_, they bounce back from the ground almost to the same height. So it's just a matter of playing with the values to get it working somehow :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Small comparison :) if there is not classic cache issue and cache is correct, than force field make speed constant even without Fall-Off.

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is my 20 cent solution (it's cheap, i know, but it works and it is pretty fast):

Of course, the higher the coins fall, the more they react. That's gravity and we all now that. So we can solve this if they fall from an even height - one after another.

So what you could do it, create a slide (this is basically a cube, from which you delete some faces and extrude it)

[image]

give it a rigid body passive, shape mesh.

Create a coin (which is basically a flat cylinder), give it rigid body active and array it over the slide, apply the array modifier and separate the object in edit mode by separate -> by loose parts.

then you get:

[image]

now, copy slide plus coins, rotate it and you got...right, more coins:

[image]

do this how often you want...10 slides.

You can randomize the coins by randomize transform before they fall on the slide so you get more realism in that:

[image]

[image]

Note: of course, put the camera in that way, it does not see the slides....!

Comment: I guess that's the best solution unless it would be possible to "spawn" the coins somehow. Maybe it's not even necessary to place the coins so far above the slides. Gravity will still accelerate them while sliding down but not as extreme as the fall from such a big height like in the original setup.

Comment: Marty won't agree with you. I am sure :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann see my other solution on this page using a Dynamic Driver, but perhaps indeed one could spawn a coin PS instead!

Answer (score 0):

The explosion might come from an object colliding (or intersecting) with your coins in the first place. Also check what type of shape you have applied to your coins in the physics tab. It might help to set them all to 'mesh' instead of 'convex hull' which is the default.
You can use an array modifier in the first place to generate an accurate stack of coins close to the truck. But having a tall stack as you have, it is more likely they will fall, of course, and they should, as this is true to how the physics acts in our real world. Hope some of my tips will help. :)

Comment: I didn't have the impression Jeremy was wondering where the explosion comes from, it was more an explanation why he can't let them all start from the same location. And I wouldn't use _Mesh_ if it's not necessary. Like the _Blender Manual_ says: "Primitive shapes (Box, Sphere, Capsule, Cylinder, and Cone) are best in terms of memory and performance but do not necessarily reflect the actual shape of the object." So instead of changing from the default _Convex Hull_ to the less performant _Mesh_, I'd rather switch to _Cylinder_, since that's the shape of the coin.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a particle system to a plane above the truck, turn on advanced properties, and then go to physics for collision. Under the render tab in the particle menu, turn render as to object, then select your coin.