# Delay individual activations of Rigid Body

Tags: rigidbody

everyone! I need assistance with Rigid Body simulation in Blender. I have objects that I want to activate one by one. I've set "Start Deactivated" for all of them and adjusted the activation keyframes to different time intervals.

I even baked the rigid body simulation to ensure correctness, but regardless of the settings, deactivation occurs at a unified moment. Is there a way to shift each simulation independently?

(The option of baking the animation doesn't quite fit my needs, as the number of objects is much larger than in the test scene in the video.)

https://youtu.be/WIahXtIKLHo - example

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Probably related not the topic but addon "Copy particles to Rigid Body" https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251696/2214

Comment: are u sure that you keyframed deactivated on and off? i tried it and it worked. Since you didn't show us, pls provide blend file and tell us your blender version. thx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you keyframe "deactivated" on, and one frame later, "deactivated" off. I tried - it works.

[image]

Note: what doesn't seem to work is: if you copy an already animated rigid body with keyframes, and just move the keyframes in the timeline - it won't work. I had to delete the keyframes of the new object, and insert them manually. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the action a single action for each object then move the keyframes:

[image]

Or push down the actions in the *Dope Sheet* window in *Action Editor* mode...

[image]

...and offset each strip in the *Nonlinear Animation* window:

[image]